# LangChain and LLama index Chatbot on ingested data

Tags: chatbot, openai-api, langchain, data-retrieval, llama-index

I am new to the world of LangChain and LLama Index. I am working on a project for document consultation (building regulations) using LLMs. I noticed that when, for example, on LLama Index, I use the **query engine**, the responses are based solely on the ingested data. However, when I use the **chat engine**, the LLM also draws (if not solely) from its background knowledge. I would like to build a chatbot that only draws from my documents.

Does anyone know why? And how to resolve this issue?

Here is the code:

```
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader('./data').load_data()
parser = SimpleNodeParser()
nodes = parser.get_nodes_from_documents(documents)
index = GPTVectorStoreIndex(nodes, show_progress = True)
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
query = input()
response = query_engine.query(query)
print(response)
```

In this case if i asks something like "Who is Cristoforo Colombo?" the response is correctly "i don't know".

On the other hand, with the following code:

```
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader('./data').load_data()
parser = SimpleNodeParser()
nodes = parser.get_nodes_from_documents(documents)
index = GPTVectorStoreIndex(nodes, show_progress = True)

service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm=OpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613"))
chat_engine = index.as_chat_engine(chat_mode="openai", verbose=True, service_context = service_context)

index.as_chat_engine(chat_mode="openai", verbose=True, service_context = service_context)
query =''
while query != "stop":
    query = input()
    response = chat_engine.chat(query)
    print(response)
```

The answer seems to be taken from its background knowledge, and it knows who Christopher Columbus is

Answer (score 1):

use chat mode as 'condense_question'. It will always query the documents.